# How client knows zookeeper is lagging behind in transaction?

Tags: hbase, apache-zookeeper

Can anyone tell me what happens in following scenario

- There are five zookeeper servers s1,s2,s3,s4 and s5
- When client connected to the s3 it was up-to-date
- client made a write request to create /test node to s3 it forwarded to leader(s5)
- As s1,s2,s5 completed that request successfully,Client got the success message
- But due to network problem s3 was not able to complete the work
- And still client is connected with s3
- Now client is making read request for reading /test node to s3

What will happen now, is s3 will throw node not found error or anything else happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A client will be able to keep the connection to a server outside the quorum after a partition, only if the server was started in read-only mode and the client has requested read-only mode support while connecting. In your example, in the default mode clients will get disconnected from s3 as s3 and s4 will not be able to form a quorum and will stop serving requests from clients.

In the read-only mode, however, the client can read (but not write) data from s3. The data it reads might be stale, however. See [official doc](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.6/zookeeperAdmin.html#Experimental+Options%2FFeatures)

From zk official doc

> Read Only Mode Server (Java system property: readonlymode.enabled)
>
> New in 3.4.0: Setting this value to true enables Read Only Mode server
>   support (disabled by default). ROM allows clients sessions which
>   requested ROM support to connect to the server even when the server
>   might be partitioned from the quorum. In this mode ROM clients can
>   still read values from the ZK service, but will be unable to write
>   values and see changes from other clients. See ZOOKEEPER-784 for more
>   details.

If your client had used a connection string which included all the servers in the ensemble, it will be able to reconnect to one of the servers in the newly formed quorum and will be able to read last successful write. But on the other hand, if you had directly connected only to s3, then you will either be disconnected or will be able to read potentially stale data depending upon read-only mode was enabled or not.

In your example, the client which is connected to s3 changed the state and got successful acknowledgment, it will be able to read the same as well and will not get NoNodeException